# SQL:Insert rows with sum of DLY rows less than the WKLY rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Requirement: Is to insert rows ONLY FOR those rows whose difference b/w SUM of DLY rows are less than WKLY value and the DATES of DLY are within the range of DATES of WKLY

DDL:

```
create or replace table table_a
(
ID number,
qty number,
date_from date,
date_to date,
grain String
);

insert into tempdw.table_a values (1,102,'2020-07-04','2020-07-04','DLY');
insert into tempdw.table_a values (1,1028,'2020-07-05','2020-07-05','DLY');
insert into tempdw.table_a values (1,2828,'2020-07-06','2020-07-06','DLY');
insert into tempdw.table_a values (1,3870,'2020-07-05','2020-07-11','WKLY');
```

I need to insert a new row (yellow) with the difference of SUM of DLY(Orange) and WKLY(Green)

[image]

Tried :

select ID , sum(impression) over(partition by id , time_grain),date_from,date_to,time_grain
from tempdw.test_impress;

Comment: Hi - what is the logic for inserting the record with dates of the 7th rather than the 11th (to match the weekly record)?

Comment: The date can be any b/w the weekly dates and those not in dly date

Comment: Is it therefore impossible to have a daily record for every day of the week - so there is always a gap where you can insert this new daily record? If not (i.e. there could be 7 daily records in a week), what date do you use for the new daily record?

Comment: Since the qty is not matching we insert the new row with that difference and date to be after the DLY last date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to Snowflake but here's an example worked out (and tested with your sample data) using PostgreSQL. Hopefully you can tweak it for your own flavour of SQL.

```
INSERT INTO table_a
SELECT id,
       missing_qty,
       missing_date,
       missing_date,
       'DLY' AS grain
FROM   (  /* NOTE: Use Average of b.qty because the value repeats on each row selected */
                SELECT   a.id,
                         Cast(Avg(b.qty) - Sum(a.qty) AS INTEGER) AS missing_qty,
                         (  /* NOTE: Find an unused date in the week */ 
                                SELECT date(date_from + interval '1 day')
                                FROM   table_a
                                WHERE  grain = 'DLY'
                                AND    date_from + interval '1 day' NOT IN
                                       (
                                              SELECT date_from
                                              FROM   table_a
                                              WHERE  id = a.id
                                              AND    grain <> 'WKLY') ) AS missing_date
                FROM     table_a a
                JOIN     table_a b
                ON       a.id = b.id
                AND      a.date_from BETWEEN b.date_from AND      b.date_to
                AND      a.grain = 'DLY'
                AND      b.grain = 'WKLY'
                GROUP BY a.id ) x
WHERE  missing_qty > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work based on the data you've provided:

```
alter session set week_start = 7; -- Sets start of week to Sunday

insert into table_a (ID, qty, date_from, date_to, grain)
with t1 as (
  select *
  , concat(year(date_from),'-',week(date_from)) as year_week -- Week used to group records
  , max(date_to) over (partition by grain, year_week) as max_dly_date -- Max date already used within week
  ,dateadd(day,1,max_dly_date) as new_dly_date -- Next date after the max date
  ,sum(qty) over (partition by grain, year_week) as sum_dly_qty -- Total qty by week and grain
  from table_a
)
select dly.ID, (wkly.qty - dly.sum_dly_qty), dly.new_dly_date, dly.new_dly_date, 'DLY'
from t1 dly
inner join t1 wkly on dly.year_week = wkly.year_week and wkly.grain = 'WKLY'
where dly.grain = 'DLY' and dly.date_to = dly.max_dly_date; -- We only need one DLY record in each week
```